# Vue + axios : has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: vue.js, axios, cors

I have vue app using axios ,first made axios default values :
import axios from 'axios'

```
const token ='xxxxxxxxx'
axios.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://xxxxxxxxx/api/v1/'
```

then in a page I call axios :

```
<script>
export default {
    data : function () {
        return {
            games : []
        }
    },
    created: async function(){
       await this.axios('games/this',{withCredentials: true,}).then((res)=>  this.games=res.json)  
    }
}
</script>
```

I get this error `from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`

I tried many solution from posts in this site but don't works

Comment: what your backend is written with?

Comment: @bunbalhara backend writen with Lumen

Comment: Did you install laravel-cors? https://github.com/spatie/laravel-cors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CORS issue should be solved on the backend-side.
If you are using Lumen for backend, please make sure you installed Laravel-Cors
https://github.com/spatie/laravel-cors
Then set allowed_origins to * in the config/cors.php file.

```
...

'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

...
```

Comment: I solved it more easly ,just add `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');` to index.php on public folder